# Csgo match history acces api

Tags: api, steam

Is there an api for the history of matches in csgo? I want to make such a page similar to scope GG but I can not find any api.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The wiki page for Match history is here

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Access_Match_History

Comment: I looked at it but there is nothing there

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. The API is documented there. If that does not work for you, I suggest asking Steam Support instead.